# Shortest Path Function (Dijkstra's Algorithm)

Tags: r, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have a data frame composed of a latitude, longitude, node ID, from NodeID, to Node_ID, length. The from and to node columns are my edges. I can only travel on my edges when trying to find the shortest path. I want to be able to go from a node to another node while minimizing my total length traveled. The output should return every node I have to travel through to get to my destination. I have tried many built in packages like cppRouting and igraph, but I can not get anything to work correctly . Any ideas on how to either create a function or how to use any existing functions to accomplish this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the detailed steps used in Dijkstra’s algorithm to find the shortest path from a single source vertex to all other vertices in the given graph.

Algorithm:

1) Create a set sptSet (shortest path tree set) that keeps track of vertices included in shortest path tree, i.e., whose minimum distance from source is calculated and finalized. Initially, this set is empty.

2) Assign a distance value to all vertices in the input graph. Initialize all distance values as INFINITE. Assign distance value as 0 for the source vertex so that it is picked first.

3) While sptSet doesn’t include all vertices

….a) Pick a vertex u which is not there in sptSet and has minimum distance value.

….b) Include u to sptSet.

….c) Update distance value of all adjacent vertices of u. To update the distance values, iterate through all adjacent vertices. For every adjacent vertex v, if sum of distance value of u (from source) and weight of edge u-v, is less than the distance value of v, then update the distance value of v.

Go through the following link: [Printing Paths in Dijkstra’s Shortest Path Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-paths-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/)

Comment: Do you know of any existing functions to accomplish this also? Thank you